# Firebase rewrite issues for script and html files

Tags: firebase, url-rewriting, url-routing, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I 'm making an ecommerce website using firebase.I have multiple webpages and these pages should have a access from the root node.
Eg : www.example.com/
     www.example.com/retailer
     www.example.com/dashboard
I dont want website to be like www.example.com/retailer/dashboard

and my rewrite rules are like this

```
"hosting": {
"public": "public",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/retailer",
    "destination": "/retailer.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "/[dD][aA][sS][hH][bB][oO][aA][rR][dD]",
    "destination": "/dashboard.html"
  },

  {
    "source": "/",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  },


  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/error404.html"
  }

]
```

}

Now I have 2 issues while writing the rewriting rules of firebase

For index.html and retailer.html file my app is working on **www.example.com** and **www.example.com/retailer** respectively but when I try to access my dashboard.html through ***www.example.com/dashboard*** I m getting error.html page but I can access dashboard.html page through ***www.example.com/retailer/dashboard*** .I dont want this behavior

And my second issue is that when I am trying to get the dashboard.html page from ***www.example.com/retailer/dashboard*** then my javascript and css are not received ***at client end instead of those scripts I am getting error.html page content for my scripts*** and I m getting the same behavior for cloud functions.

Right now my project structure is like this

```
root ->
  firebase.json
  functions
  public->
        dashboard.html
        error.html
        index.html
        retailer.html
        java-scripts->
                index.js
                retailer.js
                dashboard.js
        css-scripts
        common-scripts
        config-scripts
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend removing your rewrite to `error404.html` and just renaming the file to `404.html`. This will behave in more or less the same way but will actually return a 404 response code.

You don't need a rewrite of `/` to `/index.html`, that happens automatically.

It looks like you're trying to accept any case of dashboard -- is that really necessary? What I might recommend is having a rewrite for dashboard just like you do for retailer, and a redirect for the all-caps version:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "redirects": [
      {"source": "/DASHBOARD", "destination": "/dashboard", "type": 301}
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {"source": "/retailer", "destination": "/retailer.html"},
      {"source": "/dashboard", "destination": "/dashboard.html"}
    ]
  }
}
```